# Fails to update UI after firestore listener fires

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I am trying to update my UI each time there have been changes in firestore document.
I when I check with console, I see that the listener fires each time I change document.

My listener and 'readyOrders' is @Published:

```
func getReadyOrders() {
    referance
        .collection(path)
        .document(email)
        .collection("CompletedOrders")
        .whereField("placedBy", isEqualTo: user)
        .addSnapshotListener { orderSnapshot, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                guard let snapshot = orderSnapshot?.documents else{
                    print("There is no active orders")
                    return
                }
                
                self.readyOrders = snapshot.map{ activeSnapshot -> ActiveOrder in
                    let data = activeSnapshot.data()
                    
                    var collectedItems = [MenuItem]()
                    var collectedDrinks = [DrinkItem]()
                    
                    let id = activeSnapshot.documentID
                    let placed = data["placedBy"] as? String ?? ""
                    let inZone = data["inZone"] as? String ?? ""
                    let forTable = data["forTable"] as? String ?? ""
                    let orderItems = data["orderItems"] as? [String]
                    let orderDrinks = data["orderDrinks"] as? [String]
                    let orderItemsReady = data["orderItemsReady"] as? Bool ?? false
                    let orderDrinksReady = data["orderDrinksReady"] as? Bool ?? false
                    let totalAmount = data["totalAmount"] as? Double ?? 0.00
                    
                    orderItems?.forEach({ item in
                        let parts = item.components(separatedBy: "/")
                        collectedItems.append(MenuItem(itemName: parts[0], price: Double(parts[1])))
                    })
                    
                    orderDrinks?.forEach({ drink in
                        let itemPart = drink.components(separatedBy: "/")
                        collectedDrinks.append(DrinkItem(drinkName: itemPart[0], price: Double(itemPart[1])))
                    })
                    
                    return ActiveOrder(id: id,
                                       placedBy: placed,
                                       inZone: inZone,
                                       forTable: forTable,
                                       orderItems: collectedItems,
                                       orderDrinks: collectedDrinks,
                                       orderItemsReady: orderItemsReady,
                                       orderDrinksReady: orderDrinksReady,
                                       totalAmount: totalAmount)
                }
            }
        }
}
```

View where I display all the documents
Note: This UI is updating when there is added new document or deleted current one.

```
                Section {
                ForEach(handler.readyOrders, id: \.id){ readyOrder in
                    NavigationLink{
                        OrderComplete(handler: handler, order: readyOrder, currency: currency)
                    } label: {
                        HStack{
                            Text(readyOrder.inZone!)
                            Text("- \(readyOrder.forTable!)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            } header: {
                Text("Order's ready:")
            }
```

And in this view I display the content of document, right in here the view does not update. To the file where I am displaying content I pass in the readyOrder from 'ForEach' and there I take the array in ready order and display it in 'ForEach':

```
                        ForEach(order.orderItems!, id:\.id){ item in
                        HStack{
                            Text(item.itemName!)
                            Spacer()
                            Text(currency.format(item.price!))
                                .foregroundColor(.teal)
                            Image(systemName: "arrow.left")
                                .foregroundColor(.red)
                        }
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: deleteItem)
```

I have tried many things, and I am sure there is a simple solution, that I dont quite get. Because I am new to SwiftUI.

**Edit:**

I have puted together the the code for minimal repruduction as requested so there would more context for what I am trying to do.
Model:

```
struct Order: Identifiable{

var id = UUID().uuidString
var placedBy: String?
var inZone: String?
var forTable: String?
var orderItems: [MenuItem]?
var orderDrinks: [DrinkItem]?
var orderItemsReady: Bool?
var orderDrinksReady: Bool?
var totalAmount: Double?}
```

ViewModel:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject{
@Published var orders = [Order]()

private var referance = Firestore.firestore()

func getReadyOrders() {
    referance
        .collection(path)
        .document(email)
        .collection("CompletedOrders")
        .whereField("placedBy", isEqualTo: user)
        .addSnapshotListener { orderSnapshot, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                guard let snapshot = orderSnapshot?.documents else{
                    print("There is no active orders")
                    return
                }
                
                self.readyOrders = snapshot.map{ activeSnapshot -> ActiveOrder in
                    let data = activeSnapshot.data()
                    
                    var collectedItems = [MenuItem]()
                    var collectedDrinks = [DrinkItem]()
                    
                    let id = activeSnapshot.documentID
                    let placed = data["placedBy"] as? String ?? ""
                    let inZone = data["inZone"] as? String ?? ""
                    let forTable = data["forTable"] as? String ?? ""
                    let orderItems = data["orderItems"] as? [String]
                    let orderDrinks = data["orderDrinks"] as? [String]
                    let orderItemsReady = data["orderItemsReady"] as? Bool ?? false
                    let orderDrinksReady = data["orderDrinksReady"] as? Bool ?? false
                    let totalAmount = data["totalAmount"] as? Double ?? 0.00
                    
                    orderItems?.forEach({ item in
                        let parts = item.components(separatedBy: "/")
                        collectedItems.append(MenuItem(itemName: parts[0], price: Double(parts[1])))
                    })
                    
                    orderDrinks?.forEach({ drink in
                        let itemPart = drink.components(separatedBy: "/")
                        collectedDrinks.append(DrinkItem(drinkName: itemPart[0], price: Double(itemPart[1])))
                    })
                    
                    return ActiveOrder(id: id,
                                       placedBy: placed,
                                       inZone: inZone,
                                       forTable: forTable,
                                       orderItems: collectedItems,
                                       orderDrinks: collectedDrinks,
                                       orderItemsReady: orderItemsReady,
                                       orderDrinksReady: orderDrinksReady,
                                       totalAmount: totalAmount)
                }
            }
        }
}

func delteItem(menuItem: MenuItem, from order: ActiveOrder){
  let item = menuItem.itemName! + "/" + String(menuItem.price!)
  
  let pathTo = referance.collection(path).document(email).collection("CompletedOrders").document(order.id)
      
      pathTo.getDocument { snapshot, error in
          if let document = snapshot, document.exists{
              var items = document.data()!["orderItems"] as? [String] ?? []
              let index = items.firstIndex(where: { $0 == item })
              items.remove(at: index!)
              
              pathTo.updateData(["orderItems" : items]){ error in
                  if let _ = error{
                      print("Error deleting and updating order array")
                  }
              }
          }
      }}}
```

And the veiws:

```
struct View1: View{
@ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
var body: some View{
    VStack{
        ForEach(viewModel.orders, id: \.id){ readyOrder in
            NavigationLink{
                View2(viewModel: viewModel, order: readyOrder)
            } label: {
                HStack{
                    Text(readyOrder.inZone!)
                    Text("- \(readyOrder.forTable!)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}}

struct View2: View{
@ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
var order: Order

func deleteItem(at offest: IndexSet){
    let index = offest[offest.startIndex]
    let deleteItem = order.orderItems![index]
    
    handler.delteItem(menuItem: deleteItem, from: order)
}

//In this view I want to get updated elements from document to display -> or if removed.
var body: some View{
    VStack{
        ForEach(order.orderItems!, id:\.id){ item in
            HStack{
                Text(item.itemName!)
                Spacer()
                Text(item.price!)
                    .foregroundColor(.teal)
                Image(systemName: "arrow.left")
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
            }
        }
        .onDelete(perform: deleteItem)
    }
}}
```

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: @Ioremipsum as requested I updated the question so it would provide more information about my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**
I literally dont know why but when I changed my refarance from:

```
@ObservedObject var viewModel: Viewmodel
//To the stateobject
@StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel
```

As I understand the @StateObject in swift is used first time initializing view model class, and then you should use @ObservedObject as passing the view model further. If any body could explain me why in this case the state object worked it would be nice.